# Cloud-init in kvm guests (Debian and Centos) not setting interface settings

Tags: centos, debian, kvm-virtualization, cloud-init

Im trying to use cloud-init to setup kvm guests (currently Debian 11 and CentOS Stream 8), and I am looking for help in correcting the meta-data and user-data files.
Everything else seems to work, but network interface settings aren't set, though I do see cloud-init logs showing that they are.
Please see below:

For debian:

```
    cat << EOF > /var/lib/libvirt/images/$meta_data_file
instance-id: $vm_name
local-hostname: $vm_name
hostname: $vm_name
fqdn: $vm_name
manage_etc_hosts: true
EOF

cat << EOF > /var/lib/libvirt/images/$cloud_config_file
#cloud-config

# Hostname management
preserve_hostname: false
hostname: $vm_name
fqdn: $vm_name
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        name: e*
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: 
        - 10.10.0.25/24
      gateway4: 10.10.0.254
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 10.50.0.23
          - 10.50.0.17
          - 10.50.0.18
      search: [testing,production,admin,internal]
      routes:
        - to: 10.50.0.0/24
          via: 10.10.0.249
users:
  - default
  - name: admin
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: wheel, sudo, admin
    home: /home/admin
    shell: /bin/bash
    hashed_passwd: $adminpasswd
    lock_passwd: false
    ssh_pwauth: True
    chpasswd: { expire: False }
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa ...
      - ssh-rsa ...
# only cert auth via ssh (console access can still login)
ssh_pwauth: True
disable_root: false
chpasswd:
  list: |
     root:$rtpwd
  expire: False
runcmd:
  # disable dhcp for eth0
  - [ sh, -c, sed -e '/iface eth0 inet dhcp/s/^/#/g' -i /etc/network/interfaces ]
bootcmd:
  - cloud-init-per always fix-debian-autonet rm /etc/udev/rules.d/75-cloud-ifupdown.rules
    - cloud-init-per always fix-debian-netconfig rm /run/network/interfaces.d/*
  - cloud-init-per once ifdown ifdown ens3
  - cloud-init-per once bugfix rm /run/network/interfaces.d/ens3
  - cloud-init-per once ifup ifup ens3

# Configure where output will go
output:
  all: ">> /var/log/cloud-init.log"
# configure interaction with ssh server
ssh_svcname: ssh
ssh_deletekeys: True
ssh_genkeytypes: ['rsa', 'ecdsa']
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
packages:
  - bind9-utils
  - vim
  - freeipa-client
  - cloud-utils-growpart
power_state:
  delay: "+2" #minutes
  mode: reboot
  message: Run completed
  timeout: 120 #seconds
  condition: True
EOF
```

For Centos Stream 8:

```
cat << EOF > /var/lib/libvirt/images/$cloud_config_file
#cloud-config

# Hostname management
preserve_hostname: false
hostname: $vm_name
fqdn: $vm_name
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        name: e*
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: 
        - 10.50.0.26/24
      gateway4: 10.50.0.254
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 10.15.0.23
          - 10.15.0.17
          - 10.15.0.18
      search: [testing,production,admin,internal]
      routes:
        - to: 10.15.0.0/24
          via: 10.50.0.249

users:
  - default
  - name: admin
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: wheel, sudo, admin
    home: /home/admin
    shell: /bin/bash
    hashed_passwd: $adminpasswd
    lock_passwd: false
    ssh_pwauth: True
    chpasswd: { expire: False }
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa ...
      - ssh-rsa ...
ssh_pwauth: True
disable_root: false
chpasswd:
  list: |
     root:$rtpwd
  expire: False

# Configure where output will go
output:
  all: ">> /var/log/cloud-init.log"
# configure interaction with ssh server
ssh_svcname: ssh
ssh_deletekeys: True
ssh_genkeytypes: ['rsa', 'ecdsa']
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
packages:
  - bind9-utils
  - vim
  - freeipa-client
  - cloud-utils-growpart
power_state:
  delay: "+2" #minutes
  mode: reboot
  message: Run completed
  timeout: 120 #seconds
  condition: True
EOF
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first mistake appears to be adding network configuration to `user-data`.
Got it working with a separate config file for network(`network-config`) and appropriate ENI versions for debian and centos.

For debian:

```
cat << EOF > $network_config
  version: 1
  config:
    - type: physical
      name: eth0
      subnets:
        - type: static
          address: 10.10.0.26
          gateway: 10.10.0.254
    - type: route
      destination: 10.100.0.0/24
      gateway: 10.10.0.249
    - type: nameserver
      address:
        - 10.100.0.23
        - 10.100.0.17
        - 10.100.0.18
      search:
        - testing.mydom
        - production.mydom
        - admin.mydom
EOF
```

For centos:

```
cat << EOF > $network_config
  version: 1
  config:
    - type: physical
      name: eth0
      subnets:
        - type: static
          address: 10.10.0.26
          gateway: 10.10.0.254
    - type: route
      destination: 10.100.0.0/24
      gateway: 10.10.0.249
    - type: nameserver
      address:
        - 10.100.0.23
        - 10.100.0.17
        - 10.100.0.18
      search:
        - testing.mydom
        - production.mydom
        - admin.mydom
EOF
```

We'll see what happens for Ubuntu images (and to fix package 'updation' and installation).

Comment: Debian config works fine for Ubuntu cloud images as well (tried with jammy images).